# IIFE Javascript error if passed an object with attribute within an attribute

Tags: javascript

```
var globalVar = globalVar || {};
globalVar.object1 = {};
globalVar.object1.object2 = { a: "hello" }
(function(x){
    x.hello = 'its me';
}(globalVar.object1.object2));
```

Why cant I pass globalVar.object1.object2 as an object to var x? it returns an error

VM3167:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'hello' of undefined

Comment: think of your code as the single line `globalVar.object1.object2 = { a: "hello" }
(function(x){
    x.hello = 'its me';
}(globalVar.object1.object2));` - because that's what you've written. This is an example of why `;` are important

Comment: Wow, it worked ! hahaha,Thanks ! this is just to remind me that I cannot rely on the ASI feature of javascript.

Comment: @Rodave: You can totally rely on ASI, but like anything else, you need to know a few rules. The ones who hit these snags are usually those who *don't* rely on ASI but then forget to type one. People who do rely on it would put a `;` on the same line before the `(` as a standard practice.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is because of the missing semicolon before the IIFE.

So the outer parens of the IIFE get treated like a function call trailing off the object literal, but that doesn't cause an error because the call's args get evaluated first. The argument in this case will be the result of invoking the IIFE, which means you're trying to pass `.object2` to the IIFE before the expression that assigns to `.object2` completed in full, which means `.object2` doesn't yet exist.